# How to optimize converting an unsigned arbitrary precision integer to a string for printing?

Tags: c++, integer-division, unsigned-integer, arbitrary-precision

I am working on an unsigned arbitrary precision integer class in C++, just as an exercise for myself. While running some benchmarks (calculating the Fibonacci sequence at some number) I noticed that converting my class to a string for printing was taking about 40% of the total runtime. Currently, I am using a traditional grade school approach to successively divide the integer by 10 to get the printable string and was wondering if there was a faster approach.

I have attempted to implement Newton-Raphson division but even with my Karatsuba implementation it was still substantially slower than the traditional approach.

My current idea is to generate the number 0.1 with enough precision that I can replace the division operation with a multiplication operation instead. Of course, this method has resulted in rounding errors when trying to print large numbers. An example from one of my tests:

```
Print test:   11111111112345678906735299999996
My old print: 11111111112345678906735300000000
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is there a way to know how much precision is required to calculate 0.1 such that when I multiply it by the number I am trying to print it will have no noticeable rounding error? i.e. The rounding error will get shifted away when converting back to an integer.
2. Is there some other way to optimize division by a constant when dealing with arbitrary precision? It seems to me that I can potentially find some way to use this multiplication method for the most significant bits and use the grade school method for the least significant bits but I doubt the return in runtime would be significant.

Note: I am storing my integer as an `std::vector<bool>` and am using the `-O3` optimization flag. Any information for this would be a big help! Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
My initial thought when creating this class was to keep it fairly basic. i.e. since an integer in memory is just an array of bits then that's how I'll store my bits. The storage is fairly self explanatory, if `arr` is my vector then `arr[0]` represents 2^0, and `arr[1]` is 2^1, and so on.

My initial ugly implementation of to_string for anyone wondering:

```
std::string uInt::to_string() const {
    if (*this == ZERO) return std::string("0");
    uInt n(*this), mod;
    std::string result("");
    while (n != ZERO) {
        std::pair<uInt, uInt> div_mod_result = n.div_and_mod(TEN);
        mod = div_mod_result.second;
        n = div_mod_result.first;
        if (mod == ZERO)
            result = '0' + result;
        else if (mod == ONE)
            result = '1' + result;
        else if (mod == TWO)
            result = '2' + result;
        else if (mod == THREE)
            result = '3' + result;
        else if (mod == FOUR)
            result = '4' + result;
        else if (mod == FIVE)
            result = '5' + result;
        else if (mod == SIX)
            result = '6' + result;
        else if (mod == SEVEN)
            result = '7' + result;
        else if (mod == EIGHT)
            result = '8' + result;
        else if (mod == NINE)
            result = '9' + result;
        else {
            throw std::runtime_error("ERROR: To String Failed");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

My fixed point attempt:

```
std::string uInt::to_string() const {
    if (this->bits.empty()) return std::string("0");
    uint64_t precision = this->bits.size(); // Unsure what precision would be necessary
    one_over_ten = uInt::get_one_over_ten(precision);
    mask = (ONE << precision) - ONE;
    uInt n(*this), mod;
    std::string result("");
    while (n.bits.size()) {
        floating_point_result = n * one_over_ten; // Leaves me with n/10 with precision fraction bits
        mod = ((floating_point_result & mask) * TEN) >> precision; // Extracts the fraction
                                                                   // bits, multiplies by ten,
                                                                   // then converts to an integer
        n = floating_point_result >> precision; // Turns n back into an integer
        /* Same if chain as before */
    }
    return result;
}
```

Hopefully this explains what I've been trying a little better.

Comment: Aaron, while I understand your question, I don't understand your implementation and where and how you have implemented the conversion from `std::vector<bool>` to `std::string`. Providing [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: I'm quite suspicious of this approach using floating-point arithmetic, and the use of `std::vector<bool>`.  Intuitively, I would use a larger type such as `std::vector<uint64_t>`, meaning each element holds 64 bits of data.  This makes many useful operations (_e.g._ modulo and bit-shifting) much more efficient because you can operate on many bits at once, then collect or pass on overflow bits.  Many operations can be also written in ways that lend themselves to SIMD optimization.  Note that long division can be done in binary too.

Comment: @paddy Honestly the change to an `std::vector<uint64_t>` may be enough to optimize my project significantly more than optimizing the current approach and that will be my next step in optimizing this project. Although, I am sure that even still the conversion to a string will take a similar portion of the runtime. So I am still wondering if there are faster ways of converting arbitrary precision integers to a string. Something faster than repeated long division.